# combine 2 nested dictionaries

Tags: json, ansible, yaml, jinja2

I am trying to add an additional entry to a nested dictionary. I am able to extract the nested dictionary, append to the dictionary but can't fully figure out how to replace the nested section with the newly created one. I have a feeling there is a much easier way to do this. I will just ask what I want in the end instead of posting what I have tried and see where it goes.

I need to add an additional entry under my_team that will come in as a var:

```
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  json:
    OTHER_KEYS_1: value1
    OTHER_KEYS_2:
      value1
      key1: value1
    OTHER_KEYS_3:
      key1: value1
      key2: value2
      my_team:
      - org: Default
        team: TEAM-ONE-ADMINS
      - org: Default
        team: TEAM-ONE-USERS
      - org: Default
        team: TEAM-TWO-USERS
      - org: Default
        team: TEAM-TWO-ADMINS
      - org: Default
        team: TEAM-THREE-USERS
      - org: Default
        team: TEAM-THREE-ADMINS
    OTHER_KEYS_4: {}
    OTHER_KEYS_5:
      emailAddress: someemail@mail.com
      givenName: User Name
    OTHER_KEYS_6:
      key1: value1
  msg: OK (7003 bytes)
  pragma: no-cache
  redirected: false
  server: nginx
  status: 200
  strict_transport_security: max-age=63072000
  url: https://tower/api/v2/settings/saml/?format=json
  vary: Accept, Accept-Language, Origin, Cookie
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: ***"Add an additional entry under my_team."***

A: Given simplified data

```yaml
    data:
      k1: v1
      k2: v2
      k3:
        key1: value1
        key2: value2
        my_team:
          - {org: default, team: team_one}
          - {org: default, team: team_two}
```

Declare what you want to add

```yaml
    data_add:
      k3:
        my_team:
          - {org: default, team: team_three}
```

and [combine](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) the dictionaries

```yaml
  result: "{{ [data, data_add]|combine(recursive=True, list_merge='append') }}"
```

gives the dictionary with an additional entry under *my_team*

```yaml
  result:
    k1: v1
    k2: v2
    k3:
      key1: value1
      key2: value2
      my_team:
      - {org: default, team: team_one}
      - {org: default, team: team_two}
      - {org: default, team: team_three}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    data:
      k1: v1
      k2: v2
      k3:
        key1: value1
        key2: value2
        my_team:
          - {org: default, team: team_one}
          - {org: default, team: team_two}

    data_add:
      k3:
        my_team:
          - {org: default, team: team_three}

    result: "{{ [data, data_add]|combine(recursive=True, list_merge='append') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: data|to_yaml

    - debug:
        var: result|to_yaml
```

Comment: I cannot believe this was that simple lol. I tried `combine` but wasn't nesting enough and probably half due to my enormous brain fog yesterday. Thanks @Vald! you are a rock star.